# why can't I change only a single element in a nested list in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I just met something really strange of Python:

```
>>> out=[[0]*3]*3
>>> out
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> out[0][1]
0
>>> out[0][1]=9
>>> out
[[0, 9, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 9, 0]]
```

well, obviously, what I want is :

```
[[0, 9, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

isn't strange?  I'm not very familiar with Python, but Python always impresses me with its intuitive behavior. But how it comes up with this?
... and how can I get what I need?

thanks!

Watt

Comment: You're right about one thing - it's not very intuitive. I don't think they fixed it in Python 3 either.

Comment: @MarkRansom Why do you think it is something that needs to be **fixed**? What if you actually did want this behaviour, how would that be achieved if it was changed?

Comment: For anyone wondering if people actually use this behavior correctly in code, see the the documentation on [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), which has an example for clustering sequences into n-length groups using `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)`.

Comment: yes, the problem is only about the first line. And it is somehow intuitive too now.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate of many, many other questions, but I'm somehow failing to find a good example.

Comment: @jamylak: `inner=[0,0,0]` `out=[inner for i in range(3)]` Let the usual case work as expected and the oddball case require extra work. As it is the `*3` notation is almost worthless, there are few times when you want what it gives you.

Comment: @Matt, there's a definite logic to it and once bitten you'll never forget. The problem is that *everyone* gets bitten.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, my first thought was "oh no not again." Sometimes it's just too much trouble to hunt down the duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A strange behaviour indeed, but that's only because `*` operator makes shallow copies, in your case - shallow copies of `[0, 0, 0]` list. You can use the `id()` function to make sure that these internal lists are actually the same:

```
out=[[0]*3]*3
id(out[0])
>>> 140503648365240
id(out[1])
>>> 140503648365240
id(out[2])
>>> 140503648365240
```

Comprehensions can be used to create *different* lists as follows:

```
out = [ [0]*3 for _ in range(3) ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `*` to duplicate elements in lists is a shallow copy operation, so you will end up with multiple references to the same mutable objects if you use this on a list that contains mutable objects.

Instead, use the following to initialize your nested list:

```
out = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
```

You can see that with your method, each entry in `out` is actually a reference to the same list, which is why you see the behavior that you do:

```
>>> out = [[0]*3]*3
>>> out[0] is out[1] is out[2]
True
```