# Looping through a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am new to programming and I have this basic problem I cannot fix. I simplified it as much as possible. In this simplified version, I am iterating through an empty list. I just want to store the indices in the "symmetric matrix":

```
n = 2
B = [[None] * n] * n
print B, "\n"
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        B[i][j] = [i, j]
        print B
```

Initially, the list looks like this:

```
[[None, None], [None, None]]
```

After looping trough, I would expect the print-out to be:

```
[[[0, 0], None], [None, None]]
[[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [None, None]]
[[[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], None]]
[[[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

Instead, I get this:

```
[[[0, 0], None], [[0, 0], None]]
[[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 1]]]
[[[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]]]
[[[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

What am I missing? Thanks for helping out...

Comment: Dup: [Python List Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index)

Comment: possible duplicate of [why can't I change only a single element in a nested list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941032/why-cant-i-change-only-a-single-element-in-a-nested-list-in-python), and I fear, many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need instead of the current way you're defining `B` is `n` "fresh" instances of the sublist:

```
B = [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
```

which is equivalent to but shorter and (for a Pythonista) more readable than:

```
B = []
for _ in range(n):
    B.append([None] * n)
```

This is because lists in Python are not values but objects; i.e. they are not copied by default. For example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [a, a]  # list of 2 items, both pointing to the same list instance
>>> b[0].append(1)  # b[0] refers to the same list instance also referenced by a
>>> print b
[[1], [1]]
```

whereas:

```
>>> b = [[], []]  # list of 2 distinct sublists
>>> b[0].append(1)
>>> print b
[[1], []]
```

If you apply that knowledge to

```
B = [[None] * n] * n
```

you'll see there's an error in the construction—you're creating a list that contains another list of `n` `None` values; you're then "upsizing" the list to contain `n` of such lists; however, the same list instance will be used just like in the above, more trivial examples.

**P.S.** more accurately, everything in Python is an object not a value, except in cases where the object is immutable, such as `int`s and `float`s and `str`s etc, it is as if they are values and are always copied—this is because if an object is immutable, you might as well pretend a new reference to it is a new copy of it, because it looks the same and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 3):

Your initialization creates two references to the same list:

```
n=2
B=[[None]*n]*n
for x in B:
     print id(x)
```

Output:

```
4534759576
4534759576
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do, what you want:

```
    n=2
    B = [[None for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    print B, "\n"
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
        B[i][j] = [i, j]
        print B
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding what is happening here is understanding that you are creating lists with shared references when you use the `[[None]*n]*n` method. Have a look at [this visualisation](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=n%3D2%0AB%3D%5B%5BNone%5D%2an%5D%2an%0Aprint+B,+%22%5Cn%22%0Afor+i+in+range%28n%29%3A%0A++++for+j+in+range%28n%29%3A%0A++++++++B%5Bi%5D%5Bj%5D%3D%5Bi,j%5D%0A++++++++print+B&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=true&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=3) of what your code does, it should make things more clear. [This blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) also explains how names and values work in Python.