# Python - how to explain assigning data to array in this case

Tags: python, arrays

Please see the code below, why by doing

```
array[0][0] = 'Tadaaaa'
```

changed 5 elements instead of one?

First, create an empty array:

```
x, y = 5, 3

# when you multiply it's copying, so the ids of each item is the same
array = [[set()] * y] * x
array
```

I will get:

```
[[set(), set(), set()],
 [set(), set(), set()],
 [set(), set(), set()],
 [set(), set(), set()],
 [set(), set(), set()]]
```

Then assign a value to elements:

```
array[3][2].add('BBC')
array
```

I will get:

```
[[{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}]]
```

But when I do:

```
array[0][0] = 'Tadaaaa'
array
```

I get:

```
[['Tadaaaa', {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 ['Tadaaaa', {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 ['Tadaaaa', {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 ['Tadaaaa', {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 ['Tadaaaa', {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}]]
```

What's going on here?

I thought I would get something like this:

```
[['Tadaaaa', {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}],
 [{'BBC'}, {'BBC'}, {'BBC'}]]
```

Comment: What happens if you do ([0],[0]) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, these are not arrays; they are lists.

Second, using `*` creates a list of references to the *same* `set` object, not a list of references to distinct `set` objects.

```
>>> x = [set()]*3
>>> id(x[0]), id(x[1]), id(x[2])
(4297985280, 4297985280, 4297985280)
```

Instead, use a list comprehension to ensure that `set()` is called once per element.

```
>>> x = [set() for _ in range(3)]
>>> id(x[0]), id(x[1]), id(x[2])
(4298169136, 4298363424, 4298363656)
```

You can use nested list comprehensions to get the nested list you want:

```
>>> x, y = 5, 3
>>> array = [[set() for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(x)]
>>> for x in array:
...   map(id, x)
...
[4298169136, 4298363424, 4298363656]
[4297985280, 4298363888, 4298364120]
[4298364352, 4298364584, 4298364816]
[4298365048, 4298365280, 4298365512]
[4298365744, 4298365976, 4298366208]
```

As you can see, each element in the array is a distinct `set` object.

Comment: Why does `array[3][2].add('BBC')` change all elements while `array[0][0] = 'Tadaaaa'` only changes one column?

Comment: Because the first one invokes a method on the mutable object referenced by `array[3][2]` (which is the same object referenced by *every* element of the list). The second one changes the reference stored in `array[0][0]`, overwriting the previous reference with a reference to a `str` object. You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: This is a very good article to get better understanding of value assignment. Thanks for sharing chepner!

Answer (score 0):

this is [**duplicate question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941032/why-cant-i-change-only-a-single-element-in-a-nested-list-in-python) , you are repeating the same element (empty set) by putting:

```
array = [[set()] * y] * x
```

You need to use `for` loop for initializing the array as one solution
That's all

Comment: If it's a duplicate flag it as such instead of answering it.

Comment: oh , yeah ..  , I thought my reputation doesn't allow, @MSeifert

Comment: you cannot instant-close it as duplicate but I think it only requires 50 reputation to flag it (and 5 normal flags close the question)